# getting value and label from an attribute using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

From the following `a` I need to get value from the `data-autocomplete` attribute (we have label and value in there but I need to collect only value) by using jQuery, please help.

```
<a href="nullAUS%7C6214051%7C0HOAUSAQjdBwAAAAAIAwEAAAAA2igAgAAAAAAAAABkAAAAAP....8AAAAAAAAAAABub3J0AA--" data-transition="fade" data-autocomplete="{&quot;label&quot;:&quot;North Chigwell Primary, 115 Allunga Road, CHIGWELL  TAS  7011&quot;,&quot;value&quot;:&quot;AUS|6214051|0HOAUSAQjdBwAAAAAIAwEAAAAA2igAgAAAAAAAAABkAAAAAP....8AAAAAAAAAAABub3J0AA--&quot;}" class="ui-link-inherit">North Chigwell Primary, 115 Allunga Road, CHIGWELL  TAS  7011</a>
```

This is code how I am trying :

```
callback: function (e) {

    var a = $(e.currentTarget); // access the selected item
    var address = $.trim(a.text());
    // data-autocomplete

    var moniker = $(a).attr("data-autocomplete");

    $('#addressQas').val(address);
    //$.ajax({
    new FancyAjaxinator().jsonPost({
        url: "/address/selectLine",
        //dataType: "json",
        data: {
            "moniker": moniker,
                "address": address
        },
        success: function (data) {
            //console.log(data.responseObject);
            var qasAddress = data.responseObject;
            $('#address-line1').val(qasAddress.addressLine1);
            if (qasAddress.state) {
                $('#address-line2').val(qasAddress.addressLine2);
                $('#address-townCity').val(qasAddress.suburb);
                $('#address-state').val(qasAddress.state);
                $('#address-state').parent().find('span.ui-selectmenu-text').text($("#address-state option[value=" + qasAddress.state + "]").text());
                $('#address-postcode').val(qasAddress.postcode);
                $('#address-line1').valid();
                $('#address-townCity').valid();
                $('#address-state').valid();
                $('#address-postcode').valid();
            }
            $('#QASaddressField').hide();
            $('.qasAddressFields').show();
            //setFocus();
        }
    });
    this.close;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: What code have you tried? And also, under what event do you need to capture this information?

Comment: could pls share some more code inorder to help u..

Comment: Umm, duplicate declaration of `moniker`?

Comment: sorry... while pasting i forgot to completely revert back to the position where i got stuck.. now i edited... plz help me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
var a =  $('a');// or the jQuery wrapper for the target a
var json =a.data('autocomplete');
console.log(json.value)
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/k9AeV/)

Using .attr()

```
var moniker =  $(a).attr("data-autocomplete");
var json = JSON.parse(moniker);
console.log(json.value);
```

Comment: Hes using `$(a).attr("data-autocomplete");`, which would return the same value here. Also, I think you need to parse the string to an object before accessing properties.

Comment: @Johan in that case it is a string, OP need to parse it using `JSON.parse()`

Comment: Are you saying that `data()` parses it internally?

Comment: @Johan should not be, but atleast in Chrome it seems to be looking at that now.. see the attached fiddle

Comment: @Johan the behavior seems to be consistent.. couldn't find any documentation though... checked in latest Chrome/FF and IE 9 with json2 library.... see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/k9AeV/

Comment: Yea, cool, didn't know that. However, I personally prefer to keep objects in the `$.cache` using `data()`. +1!

Comment: I need to get the value field , it should come like :
AUS|930401|0uOAUSAQjdBwAAAAAIAwEAAAAAoCmrAAAAAAAAAABkAAAAAP....8AAAAAAAAAAABub3J0aAA

Comment: @user2400504 it is getting `AUS|6214051|0HOAUSAQjdBwAAAAAIAwEAAAAA2igAgAAAAAAAAABkAAAAAP....8AAAAAAAAAAABub3J0AA-- ` from the above example